# Node.JS Error: 502 Bad Gateway | ClientDuplexStream | Google Speech API

Tags: node.js, node-modules, eventemitter, google-speech-api, bad-gateway

After a while running my node application this uncaught exception is thrown and I don't know why or where to handle it.

I've tried adding eventEmitters for error with no luck.

```
Error: 502:Bad Gateway
at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:255:19)
at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus (/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:233:8)
at /node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:762:12
```

Call Stack:

```
 Client.js 233:8: _receiveStatus     | this._emitStatusIfDone(); 
 Client.js 258:12: _emitStatusIfDone | this.emit('error', error);
 events.js 127:13: emit              | Reflect.apply(handler, this, args);
 streaming.js 130:17 google-gax/lib  | self.emit.apply(self, args);
 events.js                           | throw er;
```

If someone could help me pinpoint where/why this error is thrown, that would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue here